# TypeError when using pydantic.BaseModel with hiredis.Reader

Tags: python, redis, typeerror, pydantic, hiredis

I want to create a class of type pydantic.BaseModel that has an object of type hiredis.Reader. When I run my code, I get a TypeError. The TypeError occurs immediately.

`TypeError: cannot pickle 'hiredis.Reader' object`

```
from hiredis import Reader
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    reader: Reader = Reader(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
```

hiredis-py is a Python extension that parses the Redis protocol. hiredis itself is written in C. Maybe this is the problem that causes the error.

Have any of you had the same error and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with that by setting your model to allow arbitrary types.

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arbitrary-types-allowed

```
from hiredis import Reader
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    reader: Reader = Reader(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but I still get the same error